# Sublime Text 3 - hide unwanted folders in left pane

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

So I have a folder open in Sublime Text 3.
This folder contains a structure like this:

```js
src  
build        // I would like to hide this folder
.sass-cache  // and this folder
node_modules // and this folder
task
test
```

In the folders pane on the left (the sidebar), I get the above folders. I would like to hide some of them from view and only see the remaining folders.

Is there a way to achieve folder hiding using a list or another file which is loaded on launch?

I was thinking something like a .gitignore file or such, which just lists folders or patterns to hide things from view.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set `"folder_exclude_patterns"` and/or `"file_exclude_patterns"` in your preferences. The defaults are as follows:

```js
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"]
```

Select **`Preferences -> Settings—User`**, then add the following line:

```js
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS", "node_modules", ".sass-cache", "build"]
```

If you are working in a project, select **`Project -> Edit Project`**, and add the line above to the `"settings"` dict. In both cases, make sure the file is valid [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: It does seem as though `exclude_patterns` does not work when added to the sublime project, but does work when put in one of the dicts in "folders" like in these examples: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's a **minimum working example** for a **project file** with **excluded files and folders**:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-project", "*.sublime-workspace"],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": [".idea", "__pycache__"]
        }
    ]
}
```